# THREE.js loading obj + mtl with png textures

Tags: javascript, three.js, .obj

I'm trying to load mtl file with reference to png textures to my obj model, but I'm getting following error:

`TypeError: manager.getHandler is not a function`

here is my three.js code:

```
var loadOBJ = function(){
    var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
    mtlLoader.load( "static/pictures/3D/untitled2.mtl", function( materials ) {
            materials.preload();
            console.log(materials);

            var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(  );
            loader.load( "static/pictures/3D/jaw.obj", addModelInScene);});
};

var addModelInScene = function(object){
    model = object;
    model.rotation.y = 1.55;
    scene.add(model);
    render();
};
```

and here is the .mtl file

```
newmtl Teeth_UDIM
Ns 255.999998
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 0.480000 0.424000 0.480000
Ks 0.040000 0.040000 0.040000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
map_Kd mrm.png
```

mrm.png file is in the same directory as .mtl and .obj file. When I delete the last line from .mtl (map_Kd mrm.png) then error is not displaying, but also textures are not showing. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TypeError: manager.getHandler is not a function

This runtime error indicates that the version of `MTLLoader` is newer than your `three.js` version. You always have to ensure that the core file as well as all example files (like `OBJLoader` or `MTLLoader`) are from the same release. Using the current release or at least `R109` should solve the issue.

BTW: Errors like that can easily be avoided by using the `npm` package of `three.js` and node-based workflow with a build tool like `rollup`.

Comment: You are right. Now the .mtl file is loaded as well as .png, but textures are not applied. There is no error in consol.

Comment: Yeah, I've manage to load the textures, but now the problem is that after I export the model from blender textures are not correctly exported (object is using UDIM tiles as textures).

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with this topic, sorry. Consider to ask a new question at stackoverflow.

Comment: I will. Thanks for your help, could you please look also at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60858748/three-js-loading-modal-with-model?